# Rewriting a particular sequence in respect to inverses

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm having a large amount of difficulty on piecing together the intermediate algebra between the following formulas.

$$ \frac{n^2 + 1}{2n^2 - 3} = \cdots = \frac {1 + \frac{1}{n ^ 2}}{2 - 3\frac{1}{n^2}} $$

I feel quite ashamed for not understanding the relationship off the top of my head. But hey, can't be perfect all the time!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to see what was done.

Just take out $n^2$ common from numerator and Denominator, which will then cancel out.

So, you basically have

$$\frac{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(2-\frac{3}{n^2})}$$

Do you see it now?

Comment: Clear as day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too difficult, really:

$$\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2-3} = 1\cdot \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2-3} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\cdot \frac{n^2+1}{2n^2-3} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}(n^2+1)}{\frac{1}{n^2}(2n^2-3)} = \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}{2 - \frac{3}{n^2}}$$